# check and change value in a form field before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form and a submit button. When I click submit button I have to check a input field if its not the desired field then change it and then submit the form. Below is the code. if the user puts a number less than 25 and clicks submit button then I have to check the input value first and since it is less than 25 multiply the value by 0.90 and then submit the  How can I achieve it?`Make sure that user hits the submit button once and then condition is checked and form is submitted automatically without the user having to click the submit button again.

```
<section class="calculator-form">
    <form action="" id="calculator-form" method="post" >
    <div style="width: 23%; float: left; margin: 0 3% 0 0;">
                <input id="number" type="text" name="height"/>
           </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; margin: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0">
            <input id=" button1" type="submit"/>
        </div>

   </form>
</section>
```

Comment: so number should always be less than 25 before submitting?

Comment: no its like i have to multiply if the condition is met

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to validate the input and calculate.

```
<script>
function calculate(){

    var number = document.getElementById("number").value;

    if(number < 25){
        number = number * .90;
        document.write(number);
    }else{
        alert("Number should be less than 25");
        return false;
   }
}
</script>
```

Then call the function when the user clicks submit button by using onClick.

```
<input id=" button1" onClick="return calculate()" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

**EDIT:** Add an action to your form. $_SERVER['PHP_SEFL'] will redirect it to your current executing script. And also add `document.write(number);` in if-else statement to see the result.

`<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" id="calculator-form" method="post" >`

Comment: dont you think it should be number in place of button1

Comment: I tried the above solution and when I do console.log for the same text box it shows the original value which means the value is not changing in the text box

Comment: @ankurjain So you want to display the result value to the same text box?

Comment: No i just want that when form submits it should give the modified value as the parameter not the older value...

Comment: I have a form which is posted with the values and I get the result based on that value.... So if number is less than 25 it should be multiplied with 0.90 and then posted. So it means the result I get will be based on the value I submitted after multiplying with 0.90 which I am not getting. So it means that form is being submitted with the original value

Comment: nothing happened....My page got refreshed. I have many other fields in the forms so I guess document.write wont work

Comment: It's hard for me to construct it all for you based on your explanations. However, I have given you the idea I know you can do it using those. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

please add the following `hidden` element:

```
<section class="calculator-form">
    <form action="" id="calculator-form" method="post" >
        <input id="hidden-number" type="hidden" name="hheight" value="">
        <div style="width: 23%; float: left; margin: 0 3% 0 0;">
                <input id="number" type="text" name="height"/>
           </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; margin: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0">
            <input id=" button1" type="submit"/>
        </div>

   </form>
</section>
```

and inside the script update the hidden input

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#calculator-form").submit(function(){ //bind to submit trigger
        var input=$("#number");
        if (input.val()<25){ // check if the value is less than 25
            $("#hidden-number").val((input.val)*0.90); // update the value with the new value and submit
        }
    });
});
```

then in your back end, instead of reading from `height` read from `hheight`

```
$height=$_POST['hheight'];
```

Comment: The value is changed but the changed value should not be shown in the text box....but submitted with the form..how can I achieve it

Comment: to achieve this you need to add a `hidden` tag, please check my answer,i updated it